# Is it possible to use searchsorted with a MultiIndex index in Pandas?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, fuzzy-search

I have a DataFrame that has a MultiIndex index. It can be regenerated as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn as randn
from numpy.random import randint as randint
from datetime import datetime
# setup data
obs1 = [ob if ob > 0 else ob *-1 for ob in randn(10)*100]
obs2 = [randint(1000) for i in range(10)]
labels = ['A12', 'B12', 'A12', 'A12', 'A12','B12', 'A12','B12', 'A13', 'B13']
dates = [datetime(2012, 11, i) for i in range(1,11)]
dates[0] = dates[1]
dates[5] = dates[6]
# setup index and dataframe
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(dates, labels), names=['date', 'label'])
data_dict = {'observation1':obs1, 'observation2':obs2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict, index=m_idx)
```

OUTPUT:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                  observation1  observation2
date       label                            
2012-11-02 A12       79.373668           224
           B12      130.841316           477
2012-11-03 A12       45.312814           835
2012-11-04 A12      163.776946           623
2012-11-05 A12      115.449437           722
2012-11-07 B12       38.537737           842
           A12       84.807516           396
2012-11-08 B12       35.186265           707
2012-11-09 A13       60.171620           336
2012-11-10 B13      123.750614           540
```

Dates of Interest:

```
dates_of_interest = [datetime(2012,11,1), datetime(2012,11,6)]
```

I am interested in creating a dataframe with a subset of the following criteria:

- date is nearest to one of the dates of interest
- label has 'A' in the string

So the result of my subindex would look like the following:

```
                  observation1  observation2
date       label                            
2012-11-02 A12       79.373668           224
2012-11-07 A12       84.807516           396
```

Ideally, I would be able to get data for all observations "near" the criteria, so that the return dataset might look like:

```
                  observation1  observation2
date       label                            
2012-11-02 A12       79.373668           224
2012-11-05 A12      115.449437           722
2012-11-07 A12       84.807516           396
```

But for a start I would just be happy to get the first result. I suspect that I need to use searchsort and asof, but I am not quite sure how to do that with. A MultiIndex.

Does anyone know how to get there from here?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Using `Series.asof` is a natural way to go, but I see some drawbacks:

- You're looking for a *near* timestamp, where `asof` searches for the *latest* timestamp.
  In your example, if you search for `datetime(2012, 11, 1)` (earlier than any entry in `df`), **you'll get a `NaN` value**.
- It is only applied to a time series, so you would have to apply `reset_index` to your `DataFrame`
  and then select some arbitrary column as the time series. In other words, it makes your code a bit awkward and convoluted.

Here's a more robust alternative that addresses your first task, whereby you search the time-stamp index for approximate hits using [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

# it is important that df is sorted by date
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

dates_ix = df.index.levels[0]
nearest_date = lambda date: dates_ix[np.searchsorted(dates_ix, date)]
approx_dates = map(nearest_date, dates_of_interest)
# select the desired entries in the index
df.select(lambda (date, label): (date in approx_dates and 
                                 label.find('A')!=-1))
```